# New to LWC. Trying to learn using LWC components with VS Code

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components

My objective is to play around with LWC components at
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/documentation
by reading documentation and develop these concise LWC programs using Visual Studio Code.
However its overwhelming given the fact i am fairly new to LWC.
I have had basic training of LWC and know about JS, HTML. I have pretty decent hands on with Apex
and a good understanding of SF Admin.

Could anyone please help me to get started and learn little bit of LWC?
For example - could someone please tell me how to go about developing a basic and next advanced
version of Datatable (included in link above) just by reading the documentation and sample.

Comment: you should refer to Trailheads instead of this forum. there are plenty of resources and practical exercises for you to learn.

Answer (score 1):

With any sort of programming/development - like with mathematics - reading can be helpful and highly beneficial, but it will only get you so far.  You have to "roll up your sleeves" and "get your hands dirty" by creating and failing and learning from your failures. *(You also learn from your successes, but - at least for me - I quite often remember the things I messed up and had to correct.)*

Also, again similar to mathematics, you need to learn and create incrementally. You don't start your mathematics journey by trying to do differential equations. You have to learn the basics and build on top of that. Trying to get too advanced too soon is cause for more frustration.

That said, I highly suggest you go through the Salesforce Trailhead **Build Lightning Web Components** Trail: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/trails/build-lightning-web-components

- The Trail starts with two projects - one is a Quick Start, which are
  usually quite easy and beneficial to start getting you familiar with
  whatever the concept is.
- Then there are six modules that build on the basics and go through
  testing and troubleshooting.
- It ends with two more advanced projects - one where you build an app,
  and one to communicate between LWCs.

*(If you are not already signed up for Trailhead, it is free.)*

---

After completing that Trail, you should then be able to dive into datatable.

Here are a few datatable resources that look good on the surface, but I can't vouch for because I haven't read in detail or gone through them:

https://www.sfdcpoint.com/salesforce/lightning-web-component-lightning-datatable/

https://salesforceprofs.com/custom-types-in-lwc-lightning-datatable/

https://newstechnologystuff.com/2019/02/02/lightning-web-components-datatable-with-lds-and-apex/